# Right place to create an function to determine and set application language

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2, locale

My application contains several languages based on domain extension. The language will be used for database queries and set the right locale.

I am wondering what is the right way or place to set the language setter/getter for get the language?

I have two scenario's for myself at the moment.

1. I create a class inside my own vendor lib which I can call inside Module.php to set the right translation, or else where to get the right language code for the queries.
2. I create a function inside my Application/Model/Language to set or get application language in Module.php and get the language in controllers and or database models.

The application model described;

Application structure will handle a couple of languages with exactly the same code. The text will be translated through the ZF2 translation module but I just need to determine language against extension.

I wrote a simple function to determine the application language to be used and set the locale by this output. The correct language has been set now but I still need input for my queries (a where clause containing the language code to receive the matched rows for the determined language).

An example of the function I wrote;

In Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
        $application         = $e->getApplication();
        $eventManager        = $application->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        # Set application language
        $appLanguage = $this->_setApplicationLanguage();
        $translator  = $application->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $translator->setLocale($appLanguage);
}

private function _setLanguage()
{
        # Default language
        $language = 'nl_NL';

        # Supported languages (will be served by database later)
        $aSupportedLanguages = array('en_US' => 'en', 'de_DE' => 'de', 'fr_FR' => 'fr');

        # Explode host
        $aExplode = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

        # Loop through http host parts
        foreach ($aExplode as $key => $value) {

            # Match for tld
            if (in_array($value, $aSupportedLanguages)) {
            $language = array_search($value, $aSupportedLanguages);
            break;
            }
        }
        return $language;
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you narrow the possibilities by showing us a little of your work (only relevant parts), which loads what and when so we can understand better about your business flow?

Comment: Added some code and more explanation about the application, hope this will give you a better view on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it.

1. Created LanguageController, which handles creation of new language and translating the files.
2. All translations are stored in a php array file inside a language folder. It easier to parse, work and can be cached (yay!).
3. Config for point 2.

   ```
   'translator' => [
   'locale' => 'en',
   'translation_file_patterns' => [
       [
           'base_dir' =>             __DIR__.'/../../module/Application/languages/phpArray',
           'type'     => 'phpArray',
           'pattern'  => '%s.php',
       ],
   ],
   'cache' => [
       'adapter' => [
           'name'    => 'Filesystem',
           'options' => [
               'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../data/cache/frontend',
               'ttl'       => '604800', // 1week
           ],
       ],
       'plugins' => [
           [
               'name'    => 'serializer',
               'options' => [],
           ],
           'exception_handler' => [
               'throw_exceptions' => (APP_ENV === "development"),
           ],
       ],
   ],
   ],
   ```
4. I created a controller plugin function. With that function I can easely translate anything from controllers and view files.

namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

```
final class Translate extends AbstractPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var Translator $translator
     */
    private $translator = null;

    /**
     * @param Translator $translator
     */
    public function __construct(Translator $translator = null)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __invoke($message = '')
    {
        return $this->translator->translate($message);
    }
}

namespace Application\Controller\Plugin\Factory;

use Application\Controller\Plugin\Translate;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager;

class TranslateFactory
{
    /**
     * @{inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __invoke(PluginManager $pluginManager)
    {
        $translator = $pluginManager->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get("translator")->getTranslator();

        $plugin = new Translate($translator);

        return $plugin;
    }
}
```

5. In Module.php set this code to be triggered on disptach event

   $app = $e->getApplication();
   $lang = new Container("translations");
   $translator = $sm->get('translator');

   $translator->setLocale($lang->languageName)->setFallbackLocale('en');
   $viewModel = $app->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
   $viewModel->lang = $translator->getLocale(); // for lang attr in html tag
6. In casea user wants to change the language, I have created a `languageAction()` inside my `IndexController`.